# Can you directly assign an accessor for a C# property?

Tags: c#, delegates, properties

Instead of something like this:

```
Func<bool> func;

bool Property {
    get {return func();}
}
```

I want to be able to do something like this:

```
Property.get = () => booleanReturningExpression;
```

Is that possible, or can you get me closer to that fake syntax?

Comment: Naming a delegate "Delegate" is a bad idea; it is too easily confused with System.Delegate.

Comment: If the question is limited to just syntax availability, you may want to check out the Aspect Oriented Programming options for .NET. It may be possible to decorate your property with an attribute that is interpreted by the AOP engine which could rewrite your code for you.

Comment: @ Eric I only named it that because I don't like looking at two black words in a row.  o_O

Comment: There.  I think the thumbs ups for criticizing the pseudocode were unwarranted, but have another one for inadvertently persuading me to learn about how to use Func<T>.  :-P

Comment: @Jessy: I think it's for the people who can't tell that what you're writing is pseudo-code ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, nothing like that is possible in pure C#. You can use fields or (`readonly`) properties:

```
public Func<bool> PropertyGet;
```

and assign to it, but that's not a very nice solution. If you need this feature for anything more than syntactic sugar, you could delegate from a property:

```
protected Func<bool> PropertyGet;

public bool Property {
    get { return this.PropertyGet(); }
}
```

And you'd be able to set it very similarly. Alternatively, you could mimic delegates if you *really* wanted `Property.get` and set a default method on a custom `Property` class. (I don't know if this is possible in C#, but it is in VB.NET.)